# How do I resolve errors for android studio code

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio Error Log:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.1.1.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:29.1.1.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.1.1.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:29.1.1.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.1.1.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
```

Comment: could you provide your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because there is no Support library version `29.1.1` yet. The latest version is `28.0.0` see the [Recent Support Library Revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html). You need to migrate to [androidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) to use the latest changes of Android support libraries.